# Buttons in a list with CSS columns change columns when clicked

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of buttons in a list with CSS columns defined. The list displays fine originally, but when I click the button on the bottom of the list, it moves to the top of the next column, leaving a hole in its place. When clicked again, in its new place, it moves back to its own place.

The class is defined like this:

```
.Col5 {
    columns: 5;
    -webkit-columns: 5;
    -moz-columns: 5;
}
```

Comment: Maybe... a few more lines of code ? Or better, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ! Thanks.

Comment: There is no code. Just HTML and CSS. I believe the bounding box changes when the button is selected, but don't know how to handle it.

Comment: I think zessx is talking about HTML code

Comment: Does this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/D9bZu/) illustrate something similar to your problem? Comment out the `button` CSS setting before trying. If it is the same then try to fix it by adding that `outline` property.

Comment: @Harry, thanks! That did the trick. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the issue by nullifying the outline on the button.

```
button{
    outline: none;
}
```

**Update:** Actually, the issue seems to be because for the `button:focus`, the browser (atleast Webkit) seems to be adding a CSS like below:

```
button:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

So just resetting that behavior like one of the below methods should solve the issue.

```
button:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
}

/* OR */

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/D9bZu/)